# Login using WebRequest and WebResponse class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello all I having an issue in logging into a website using webRequest and WebResponse. 
I thought let me reach out to experts by posting a question.
I am trying to login in http://www.mbhatt.in and want to access the page after the login is successfull. 
I used following code to do so. But somehow it failed

```
string poststring = string.Format("Username={0}&Password={1}", Username, Password);
byte[] postdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(poststring);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = postdata.Length;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
Stream writer = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
writer.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
cookies.Add(webResponse.Cookies);
```

I dont know what to do when cookie gets added to my browzer. How can i use this cookie to access the other pages of that website after loging in. I want to do this using WebRequest and WebResponse .

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `CookieContainer` and assign it to the web request, for example:

```
var cc = new CookieContainer();
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://.../");

request.CookieContainer = cc;
```

You will need to pass in the same container for all your requests so that the correct cookies are shared and you have a proper *session* set up.

There's a blog on MSDN [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/08/16/452347.aspx) that discusses this further and provides a larger example set.

Comment: How to use this cookie to access the next page which opens after successfull login.

Comment: As I've said, you need to pass the container into ALL requests you make where you need to share cookies.

Comment: Lloyd, how can i know that i have logged in successfully using WebRequest and WebResponse

Comment: That depends on the site, you'd have to check for the relevant success cookies in the container etc.

Comment: Lloyd. Is there anyother way apart from using CookieCollection